# display item with multiple values from listbox into textbox using access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to display item values in their respective textbox when an item is selected in the listbox

this is how I have it set up:

1. This is how the values are shown to the list box

   ```
           command.CommandText = "select * from ItemsList";
           OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               EditItemBrowserBox.Items.Add(reader["ID"].ToString() + "         " + reader["ItemBrand"].ToString() + "  " + reader["ItemName"].ToString() + "  " + reader["ItemType"].ToString() + "  " + reader["ItemPrice"].ToString());   
           }
   ```
2. This is how i'm trying to make the values from the listbox show to a textbox

   ```
           command.CommandText = "select * from ItemsList where ItemName='" + EditItemBrowserBox.Text + "' ";
           OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               EditIDTB.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
               ItemNameAddTB.Text = reader["ItemName"].ToString();
               ItemTypeAddTB.Text = reader["ItemType"].ToString();
               ItemBrandAddTB.Text = reader["ItemBrand"].ToString();
               ItemPriceAddTB.Text = reader["ItemPrice"].ToString();
           }
   ```

EditItemBrowserBox is the listbox and `EditIDTB.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();`is me trying to show the value in one of the textboxes.

Right now, when I click on an item nothing shows in the text boxes. Any help appreciated

Comment: so how would I be able to make it look for the value in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better ways to accomplish what you're doing, so you can take advantage of `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`, but the problem you're having stems from using the entire `Text` field that you're displaying to the user.

If their selection looked like this:

```
001     Acme  Anvil  Weapon  10.00
```

Then your query ends up being:

```
select * from ItemsList where ItemName='001     Acme  Anvil  Weapon  10.00'
```

Just split the part off you're interested in:

```
var itemName =
    EditItemBrowserBox.Text.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2];

command.CommandText = $"select * from ItemsList where ItemName='{itemName}'";
```

To get around issues with item names that have multiple spaces, you might want to select based on the ID instead:

```
var id = EditItemBrowserBox.Text.Split(' ')[0];

command.CommandText = $"select * from ItemsList where ID='{id}'";
```

You might also want to check into parameterizing your queries, but that's a different issue...

Comment: it works thank you very much, but it only works when the ItemName is a single word but it doesn't work when there are 2 words in the item name, I made sure to split when there are 2 spaces only

Comment: i'll look into it, thank you, I wish I could upvote you

Comment: just so that people can see: To be able to use spaces, you can sort by ID instead of itemname